# Taking a power of a polynomial to make it symmetric

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetric-polynomials

Suppose I have a non-symmetric multi-variable polynomial in $n$ variables $P(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. For example $P$ might be $x_1^2+x_2$ or $x_1-x_2$

Under what conditions will some power $m$ of $P$ (that is $P(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)^m$) be a symmetric polynomial in $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$?

For example it seems like there is no such $m$ in the case of $x_1^2+x_2$.

But there is such an $m$ in the case of  $x_1-x_2$ since $(x_1-x_2)^2=x_1^2-2x_1x_2+x_2^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: this will happen if and only if every permutation of the variables multiplies $P$ by some root of unity.

If $P\circ\sigma = \zeta_\sigma P$ for every permutation $\sigma$, then $P^n$ will be symmetric, where $n$ is the least common multiple of the orders of the $\zeta_\sigma$, because $P^n \circ \sigma = (P\circ \sigma)^n = (\zeta_\sigma P)^n = \zeta_\sigma^n P^n = P^n$.

On the other hand, if $P^n$ is symmetric, then, for any permutation $\sigma$, we have $(P\circ \sigma)^n = P^n$, so $P\circ \sigma$ and $P$ have the same irreducible factors with the same multiplicity, hence $P\circ \sigma = aP$ for some constant $a$ with $a^n = 1$.

But this cannot really happen if the full symmetry group is acting!—since a symmetry group is generated by transpositions, we can have at most order $2$ behavior.  And since two transpositions generate a symmetry of order $3$, there are only two possibilities: either $P$ is symmetric already, or it is antisymmetric in every pair of variables (e.g. $(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)(b-c)(b-d)(c-d)$).

These examples are fairly interesting, actually—they are [Vandermonde determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Properties), which pick out the sign of the acting permutation.  Specifically, the antisymmetric polynomials are those which are the product $\prod_{i<j} (x_i -x_j)$ times any symmetric polynomial.

If you require only cyclic symmetry, then you will get interesting examples of every degree, however, e.g. $(a+ib-c-id)^4$ is invariant under the transformation $a\mapsto b\mapsto c\mapsto d\mapsto a$.

Comment: No power of $z(x-y)$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Goos Yes, that was a bit hasty. The case I was after was just symmetry. :)

Comment: Yeah.  +1.  If my thinking is not too confused, this means that the solutions are: $P$ symmetric, or $P = (x_1 - x_2)(x_1 - x_3)\cdots(x_1-x_n)(x_2-x_3)\cdots$ times a symmetric polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for this nice reply. There is one thing I'm unable to really get on an "intuitive" level - namely why is it true that $P^n \circ \sigma = (P \circ \sigma)^n$. Is there some short proof of that?

Comment: @Goos That's right.  I'll clarify that.

Comment: @Timotej Well, intuitively, a symmetry needs to respect the ring operations or we wouldn't call it a symmetry.  The point is that if we want to switch, say, $P(x,y,z)\cdot P(x,y,z)$ to $P(y,x,z)\cdot P(y,x,z)$, then it doesn't matter whether we switch $x$ and $y$ first, then square, or square first, then switch $x$ and $y$.  In general, $\sigma P(x,y,z,\ldots) = P(\sigma x, \sigma y, \sigma z, \ldots)$, which you can also take as the definition of the permutation $x\mapsto y \mapsto x$.

Comment: Thanks. I guess another way to intuitively see this is to note that "renaming" the variables can never affect the outcome of a computation and "permuting the variables" can be thought of as renaming them.